# C# Process.Start() performance

Tags: c#

My testing seems to suggest that Process.Start() at its bare bones costs ~15-27ms (depending on if you use CreateNoWindow, which ADDS ~10ms).  In this question, I'm not trying to say the code I'm running is slow, but the actual act of starting a process, even if it does nothing.

I got these numbers by using a stopwatch on a console app that ran another console app literally just returning in its main method.

```
namespace RunNothing
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\Users\Noggog\Documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\DoNothing\DoNothing\bin\Release\DoNothing.exe")
            {
                CreateNoWindow = true,
                UseShellExecute = false,
            };
            var sw = new Stopwatch();
            var proc = new Process()
            {
                StartInfo = startInfo,
                EnableRaisingEvents = true
            };
            proc.Exited += (sender, a) =>
            {
                sw.Stop();
                System.Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            };
            sw.Start();
            proc.Start();
            System.Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

**So my question is whether anyone knows a good way to improve that startup time per Process.Start() call?**

For background, I have an app that will be starting various .exes, most of which should do a quick bool check and short circuit out, asap. Every so often one of the calls will do a longer operation, but usually it will do nothing.  Right now a ~15-27ms call per go is getting a bit heavy for my use case.

Edit:
Some people were asking for more details of the end usage.  [This is the project that drove the question.](https://github.com/Noggog/FishingWithGit)  The end usage is an extension of git hooks to provide more hookable commands, and provide convenience features such as calling an exe in response to hooks being fired.  One of the modes is that a single exe can handle multiple hooks, and decide which ones it would respond to.  In that scenario, every git command would "check in" with the exe to see if it wanted to do any logic.  This is where the Process.Start() time adds up.  If you have 6 repos and your git client is initializing things by running several commands a pre and post hook combo can be 27ms (proc start time) * 2(pre/post) * X(commands) * 6(repos) = ~2+ seconds.  Potentially none of these commands are ones needing response, but it's already added several seconds of sluggishness to the system.

Comment: Well your process "doNothing" you're calling it from c# that runs in a JIT that JIT needs to call the system to start the shell, then if the user got the rights if he/she can execute the .exe and the .exe is compiled from c# so that has to boot etc and loaded into JIT. There is more going on under the hood ^^, You should preload stuff into the memory / JIT etc to have real performance on the ms

Comment: You might want to consider compiling your other project to a library (DoNothing.dll) and include it in your main project. Much faster.

Comment: Agreed.  The purpose of the end app is to allow outside users to drag/drop in exes, so I don't have knowledge ahead of time to include them.

@SanderVisser Is there a way I can preload an exe so that running it a second time in the same "go" will result in the 2nd Start() going faster?  I don't know which exe it will be at compile time.

Comment: "allow outside users to drag/drop in exes" Never ever trust an outside user that has the ability to execute .exes. 

Isolated containers in docker https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker and dotnetcore (but .exe can be a lot). First thought. But those 50ms to boot is not the biggest concern.

Comment: The end goal is to extend git hooks.  Is this different and more dangerous than the standard allowing them to run a python or bash script as a hook?  Either way, it's still a route to run any custom code you drop in

Comment: This smells like an XY problem. I would advise editing your question to explain what you are _actually_ trying to do and explain why a 27ms delay is a problem rather than asking how to do something that may be impossible.

Comment: I can edit it to give more detail.  I didn't want to go into end usage details too much, so I just boiled it down to the core problem.  If it's helpful i'll add in some more back info.